# php how to check if system commands are available for use?

Tags: php

How do i check if system commands like exec() , popen() , etc are available to use ?

Something like this :

```
<?php
function($cmd)
{
if($cmd available)
{
//do nothing
}
else
{
exit();
}
}
?>
```

And check if the php file has access to a command eg. If safe mode is on it should return false.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at `function_exists()`

Comment: And if same mode is on. Then what will it return on socket function because it exists but u still cany use it

Comment: You could check if safe mode is on? `ini_get('safe_mode')` or something. Safe mode is deprecated in 5.3+ I think.

Comment: But if safe_mode is on and only exec() cmd is not allowed ?

Answer (score 0):

If safe mode is on, all system commands like `system(), exec(), passthru(), shell_exec(), popen()`, etc are not available. So, you can exit immediately in that case.

If it is off, you can check if command-execution functions are available with e. g. `function_exists('exec')`